# How-To: groupBy in an ng-repeat to get count of items in group

Tags: angularjs

I have a list pulled from C#. I'll call it Teams. Teams has a few properties: Team Type, and Team Members (which is a subset list).

```
[
  {
    "team": {
      "teamName": "The First Team",
      "teamType": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "team": {
      "teamName": "The Second Team",
      "teamType": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "team": {
      "teamName": "The Third Team",
      "teamType": 2
    }
  }
]
```

**My goal:**
I'd like to have an ng-repeat where it I show the team type, and how many teams of that type there are, kind of like so:

```
<div>
    <li ng-repeat="team in teams | groupBy: teamType>
       Type: {{::teamType}} -- Count: {{::numberOfTeamsOfType}}
    </li>
</div>
```

and it might look like this:

- Type: 1 -- Count: 1
- Type: 2 -- Count: 2

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [**angular-filter#groupby**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

Answer (score 2):

Using the angular-filter module `var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);` and given the object array structure you have provided, you can do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in teams | groupBy: 'team.teamType'">
    Team Type: {{value[0].team.teamType}} -- Count: {{value.length}}
</li>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r1rqkhmj/)